# BigQuery, tableUnavailable error while querying and streaming data into

Tags: streaming, google-bigquery, querying

I am trying to one of my BigQuery tables but I get this error:

```
Errors:
Something went wrong with the table you queried. Contact the table owner for assistance. (error code: tableUnavailable)
```

I used to be able to run the query until couple of hour ago without a problem and I still can query another table in a different data set.

I was also running a Python application to stream data into the this table, but now on:

```
table.insert_data(rows)
```

Causes this erro:

```
google.cloud.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable:
503 Error encountered during execution. Retrying may solve the problem.
(POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/#myProjectId#/datasets/#myDatasetName#/tables/#myTableName#/insertAll)
```

I have read similar questions here but can't find any solution to this problem.

Here is the latest error jobId

```
"jobId": "bquijob_6491e032_15846c06c18"
```

This has been going for a while now, can anybody help?

Comment: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/bigquery/18022

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlyant

Comment: Question should be closed/answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a hopefully rare BigQuery incident:

https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/bigquery/18022